# Scraping a table on Barchart website using python - Extract oil options data Strike,Open Int for contrat

Tags: screen-scraping

I am trying to extract price options data on this asset, but without success. Could someone please help me.
I would like to access data from the Crude Oil WTI Nov '23 (CLX23) contract.
But accessing data only from the CLX23 contract, all Strikes, calls and puts at all price levels.

How is it possible to do this?

I believe the problem must be in the

'list': 'futures.contractInRoot',

or

'root': 'CL',

But I don't know the criteria for which value to change here.

---

I would like to see the result below;

```
Type    Last    Volume  Open Int    Premium Strike  Type    Last    Volume  Open Int    Premium
Call    9.86s   18  1,195   9,860.00    80,5    Put 0.36s   39  1   360.00
Call    9.40s   2   842 9,400.00    81  Put 0.40s   1,172   2,9 400.00
Call    8.95s   N/A 1,226   8,950.00    81,5    Put 0.44s   122 1,2 440.00
Call    8.50s   N/A 1,575   8,500.00    82  Put 0.49s   499 9,7 490.00
Call    8.05s   N/A 516 8,050.00    82,5    Put 0.54s   98  1,6 540.00
Call    7.62s   1   1,613   7,620.00    83  Put 0.61s   1,707   6,8 610.00
Call    7.19s   2   595 7,190.00    83,5    Put 0.68s   175 781 680.00
Call    6.77s   12  3,365   6,770.00    84  Put 0.76s   391 4,4 760.00
Call    6.36s   N/A 641 6,360.00    84,5    Put 0.84s   175 1,2 840.00
Call    5.95s   118 7,557   5,950.00    85  Put 0.94s   3,016   13,1    940.00
```

---

But it's coming like this;

```
symbol   contractSymbol lastPrice priceChange openPrice highPrice  lowPrice previousPrice   volume openInterest tradeTime symbolCode  symbolType hasOptions
0    CLX23  CLX23 (Nov '23)    89.68s       -0.35     90.55     90.83    89.03         90.03  312,103      364,188  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
1    CLY00     CLY00 (Cash)    90.03s       +0.40     90.03     90.03    90.03         89.63      N/A          N/A  09/22/23        FUT           2        Yes
2    CLZ23  CLZ23 (Dec '23)    88.17s       -0.18     88.83     89.07    87.52         88.35  154,249      262,392  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
3    CLF24  CLF24 (Jan '24)    86.70s       -0.06     87.07     87.39    86.05         86.76   74,807      136,480  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
4    CLG24  CLG24 (Feb '24)    85.29s       -0.04     85.61     85.85    84.65         85.33   38,354       70,538  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
..     ...              ...       ...         ...       ...       .    ..      ...           ...      ...          ...       ...        ...         ...        ...
120  CLV33  CLV33 (Oct '33)    55.58s       +0.46       N/A     55.58    55.58         55.12      N/A          N/A  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
121  CLX33  CLX33 (Nov '33)    55.46s       +0.46       N/A     55.46    55.46         55.00      N/A          N/A  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
122  CLZ33  CLZ33 (Dec '33)    55.34s       +0.46       N/A     55.34    55.34         54.88      N/A            4  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
123  CLF34  CLF34 (Jan '34)    55.27s       +0.46       N/A     55.27    55.27         54.81      N/A          N/A  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
124  CLG34  CLG34 (Feb '34)    55.21s       +0.46       N/A     55.21    55.21         54.75      N/A          N/A  09/25/23        FUT           2        Yes
```

Thanks :)

---

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote
import json
import pandas as pd

geturl=r'https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CLX23/options/nov-23'
apiurl=r'https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get'


getheaders={

    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'
    }

getpay={
    'page': 'all'
}

s=requests.Session()
r=s.get(geturl,params=getpay, headers=getheaders)



headers={
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'referer': 'https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CLX23/options/nov-23',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36',
    'x-xsrf-token': unquote(unquote(s.cookies.get_dict()['XSRF-TOKEN']))

}


payload={
    "symbol":"CLX23",
    'fields': 'symbol,contractSymbol,lastPrice,priceChange,openPrice,highPrice,lowPrice,previousPrice,volume,openInterest,tradeTime,symbolCode,symbolType,hasOptions',
    'list': 'futures.contractInRoot',
    'root': 'CL',
    'meta': 'field.shortName,field.type,field.description',
    'hasOptions': 'true',
    'raw': '1'

}


r=s.get(apiurl,params=payload,headers=headers).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r['data']).iloc[:, :-1]

print(df)
```

I tried code above

and I hope to see strike data with Open Int and volume by price level

Comment: Please, read [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)